# Dictionaries - finding and updating entries from a text file of dictionary information

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nested

I am trying to enable my code to allow someone to update and remove homes from an inventory, which is stored as a dictionary. Here is my code:

```
import random
import ast

all_homes = {} #Empty dictionary created to house inventory (get it?)

class Home_Inventory:
    """
    A class for available homes in inventory. 
    Options include adding, modifying, and removing houses. 
    Allows user to output dictionary to text file for ease of reading.
   """

     def __init__(self, sqrft, adr, city, state, zipcode, model, status):
        self.sqrft = sqrft + 'square feet'    # given integer
        self.address = adr
        self.zipcode = zipcode 
        self.city = city
        self.state = state
        self.model = model
        self.status = status #sold/available/contract

    def new_home(self):   # Add a new home to list
        adr = input('Enter street address: ')
        city = input('Enter city: ')
        state = input('Enter two-letter state acronym: ')
        zipcode = int(input('Enter zipcode: '))
        model = input('Enter model name: ')
        sqrft = int(input('Enter whole square feet: '))
        status = input('Is the house available, sold, or under contract?')

        home_attr = {'a':adr, 'c':city, 's':state, 'z':zipcode, 'f':sqrft, 'm':model, 'u':status}
        id_number = random.randint(1000,9999)   # Create an ID number for each house for easy finding
        all_homes[id_number] = home_attr

        print('Home successfully added to database.')

    def del_home(self):  # Delete a sold home from list
        del_home = input('ID number of sold home: ')
        if del_home in all_homes.keys(): # Make sure it exists in list
            del[del_home]
            print('This home has been deleted from database.')
        else:
            print('Not found.')

    def update_home(self):  # Modify attributes of home
        update_home = input('ID number of the house to modify:')

        if update_home in all_homes.keys(): # Make sure it exists in list
            edit_attr = input('Please select attribute to edit\n(f:feet, a: address, c: city, s: state, z: zipcode, m: model, u: status): ')
            updated_attr = input('Please enter updated value: ')
            all_homes[update_home].updatehome_attr(edit_attr, updated_attr)
        else: 
            print('Not found.')

    def output(self):     # Prints text file of listed homes
        f = open("HomeInventory.txt","a")   # Opens (or creates) a text file
        f.write(str(all_homes))   # Writes dictionary to text file
        f.close()   # Closes file

while True:
    print("1. Add a home")
    print("2. Remove a home")
    print("3. Update home")
    print("4. Print inventory")
    print("5. Exit program")
    user_wants=input("What would you like to do today? ")
    if user_wants=="1":
        Home_Inventory.new_home(input)
    elif user_wants=="2":
        Home_Inventory.del_home(input)
    elif user_wants=="3":
        Home_Inventory.update_home(input)
    elif user_wants=="4":
        Home_Inventory.output(input)
        print(all_homes)
    elif user_wants=="5":
        print("\n Thank you for using home inventory.")
        break
```

In particular: no matter what I've tried, I can't seem to update or delete the homes in the dictionary for some reason. I feed the key (the ID number) and continuously get "not found" results.

Also, I can't seem to figure out how to get the dictionary to allow an update of only one attribute, since I can't even get the dictionary to pull a found address anyway... I've added the ID numbers to make it hopefully simpler to find target properties for updating/deleting, but it's not seeming to help much.

Also, I would like to be able to open the HomeInventory.txt file and read the dictionaries already created in it to the program each time it opens, so that users can exit the program and then re-enter and modify a house that was put in during a previous session, but I'm not sure how to go about that... Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Alright, I figured out why I couldn't get the dictionary keys to pull correctly - I needed to ensure I was passing an integer instead of a string for the ID number key! :)

Answer (score 0):

`del[del_home]` creates the list `[del_home]` and then deletes it. Not quite useful.

You meant `del all_homes[del_home]`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
update_home = input('ID number of the house to modify:')
```

should have been:

```
update_home = int(input('ID number of the house to modify:'))
```

since the key was an integer, not a string. Very simple fix that has been driving me crazy for a day now!

For the attributes, I changed the coding around to use a single dictionary for the home attributes:

```
home_attr = {'a':address, 'c':city, 's':state, 'z':zipcode, 'f':feet, 'm':model, 'u':status}
```

and then asked the user to input the key for the attribute they wanted to edit, as so:

```
    edit_attr = str(input("Please select attribute to edit\n('f':feet, 'a': address, 'c': city, 's': state, 'z': zipcode, 'm': model, 'u': status): "))
    updated_attr = input('Please enter updated value: ')
    new_home_attr = all_homes[update_home_id]
    new_home_attr[edit_attr] = updated_attr
    all_homes[update_home_id] = new_home_attr
```

I still can't figure out how to read the dictionaries from the text file and then only import new ones, but that is beyond the scope of the class anyway.